# How do I find the average of the price?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to store the data in a 2D array and then print the average of the price which has available option "no", can anybody help to find the average.

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double total = 0;
        Products[][] names = new Products[][]{
                {new Products("k7580", 6500, "yes")},
                {new Products("k8570", 7333, "no")},
                {new Products("k8580", 766, "no")},
                {new Products("k6580", 288, "yes")}
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < names[i].length; j++) {
                String available = names[i][j].getAvailable();
                if (available.equals("no")) {
                    total = total + names[i][j].getPrice();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        // from here I am not able to find average
        double average = total / names.length;
        System.out.println("average of price :" + average);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `names.length` is not the number of `Product` objects.  You have declared `name` as a 2-D array.  You actually need to *count* the `Product` objects.

Comment: The other solution would be to turn `names` into a 1-D array.  (Does it *need* to be 2-D for some reason that is not apparent in your example?)

Comment: As a side note, wouldn't it be better if `available` in class `Products` (which should probably be `Product`, anyway) was a boolean instead of a "yes"/"no" string?

Comment: yes that was awesome response you   guys . no i have table with available column name with "yes " or no option on it so  i have to go with  question and also it is mandatory to keep data in 2d array .

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a `count` variable which to increment it each time according to your if condition (`available.equals("no")`) to just count the element which meet the condition:

```
double total = 0;
Products[][] names = new Products[][] { { new Products("k7580", 6500, "yes") },
        { new Products("k8570", 7333, "no") }, { new Products("k8580", 766, "no") },
        { new Products("k6580", 288, "yes") } };

int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < names[i].length; j++) {
        String available = names[i][j].getAvailable();
        if (available.equals("no")) {
            count++;
            total +=names[i][j].getPrice();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

// from here I am not able to find average

double average = total / count;
System.out.println("average of price :" + average);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use *Java 8* or higher, you can use it:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Products[][] names = new Products[][]{
            {new Products("k7580", 6500, "yes")},
            {new Products("k8570", 7333, "no")},
            {new Products("k8580", 766, "no")},
            {new Products("k6580", 288, "yes")}
    };

    Arrays.stream(names)
            .flatMap(array -> Arrays.stream(array))
            .filter(products -> products.getAvailable().equals("no"))
            .mapToDouble(Products::getPrice)
            .average()
            .ifPresent(average -> System.out.println(
                    "average of price: " + average));
}
```

Output is:

```
average of price: 4049.5
```

As you are seeing, it is concise. I have used [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html) here. Stream helps to reduce verbosity from code.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to define a 2d array, just maintain a 1d array of products and maintain a count of eligible items which needs to be considered for average( in your case items which are unavailable)

This code will run in a single loop without the need of nested loops.

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double total = 0;
        int notAvailableItems = 0;
        Products[] names = new Products[]{
                new Products("k7580", 6500, "yes"),
                new Products("k8570", 7333, "no"),
                new Products("k8580", 766, "no"),
                new Products("k6580", 288, "yes")};
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            Products product = names[i];
            if (product.getAvailable().equals("no")) {
                total = total + product.getPrice();
                notAvailableItems++;
            }
        }
        double average = total / (double) notAvailableItems;
        System.out.println("average of price: " + average);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
average of price: 4049.5
```